# Tesseract OCR not recognizing any character

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on a project that requires character recognition as a part of it. I am using a handwriting dataset by IAM, so all the images are more or less taken in the same conditions. I am using pictures of words that have been provided by the dataset and following these steps

- Binarizing and thresholding
- Dividing the word into the characters constituting it
- Resizing the extracted character
- Letting tesseract figure out what the English alphabet is

What I'm trying to achieve is to store characters of a person's document in folders categorized by the alphabet and maybe form a template from them later on. For this I need to know which character it is.
Here's what I get as a result - 
[image]

All the characters are properly segmented (for most cases). This is more of a tesseract question than it is a python question, but I'm using python to write the script and calling tesseract through the pytesseract wrapper. 
I'm using OpenCV to manipulate the image. Images of these letter matrices are sent as input to tesseract (handled by pytesseract). The input is not an issue, I assure you. Is there anything else I need to do for tesseract to work?

None of these characters are recognized.

Comment: What tesseract version are you using? Are you using it from cmd or from you code? What are parameters?

Comment: How many pixels tall are the letters you are passing to Tesseract?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Version 4.0. And yeah, I'm using it from code. Code calls the command 'tesseract input output' and returns the output.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Letters have a width and height of 20 and 30 pixels respectively. Plus there is a small padding I added on the borders.

Comment: We need more information about tesseract parameters. Are you experienced with tesseract? Which XXX.traineddata file are you using? Have you trained it on the handwritten dataset by yourself or downloaded traineddata files from somewhere? Are you using LSTM or not? Have you tried using tesseract from cmd?

Comment: Tried to tesseract your `pretty` and output as `preg®y`. The image is cut from above. If you provide the handwriting image samples without the green rectangles, then can do some more test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract [doesn't support handwritten text](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#can-i-use-tesseract-for-handwriting-recognition) well. You should try either ABBYY OCR for that or alternative free libraries like [Lipi Toolkit](http://lipitk.sourceforge.net/).